# How to get JSON results as particular order in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

While accessing the Json result from API with AFNetworking Library, We will get results as in different order compare to POSTMAN results

For Example:

Postman result
1
2
3
4
5

AFNetworking response
2 3 1 5 4

Why it differs from POSTMAN? Any idea? Please give some suggestion to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.
 My code sample below

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id _Nonnull formData) {
} progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id Nullable responseObject) {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"APi Success : %@",responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nullable task, NSError  _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@" APi Failed : %@",[error description]);
}];
```

Comment: Can you post a example of the JSON, because if it is not in an JSON array there is no order.

Comment: If you have control over writing the data, you could always add a timestamp or index, and then sort by that when you read it back